# How to add ban-circle on hover in disabled anchor?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an anchor tag that I would like the ban-circle glyphicon to appear when hovered. I know that adding the disabled class will only change the appearance and not its functionality. Please note that this link is not part of nav components, list or btn group, just a link that will trigger a modal when clicked.

I want to follow the behaviour when you hover on the disabled link as shown here: [Disabled links](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#nav-disabled-links)

```
<div>
    <a class="disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notAvailable">Not Available</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

use CSS

```
 a.disabled:hover {
    cursor:not-allowed
 }
```

```css
a.disabled:hover {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notAvailable">Not Available</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is nice @DavidThomas :) Appreciate it!

Comment: This was perfect exactly what I needed. At first I didn't get it working but I missed the all important ':hover'. Here is some more information on cursors and browser support https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/#browser-support